# node js express app in webstorm error

Tags: node.js, webstorm

```
juns-MacBook-Pro:~ junxie$ npm install -g express-generator
npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   parent: 'express-generator' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "express-generator"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/junxie
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
npm ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I just follow video tutorial to setup node js express configuration, and got this kind of problem, I have tried sudu chown -R 'myname' ~/.npm  and then input my password, and then input
 npm install -g express-generator, and then I got this error

Comment: Looks like you're behind a proxy; have you configured the proxy information?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes, so I should stop the proxy?